# How to fill linear in blanks in number series?

Tags: excel, vba, series, fill

I am new at VBA and trying to figure out how to fill a number series using VBA. The blanks between two numbers can be one or several cells. I want to fill it in a linear way. Note that the percentages can go up or down.

```
1............2.............3............4............5...............6.

Jan........ 4,34%.......... 4,23%..............blank..............3,21%..............5,31%..................Blank

Feb.... 10.06%...........Blank................Blank............15.41%...........17.35%...................Blank

March...Blank............5.50%..............Blank..............Blank..............7.16%....................13.21%
```

Every line corresponds to a month for a specific country and every column to the day of the month. So far the macro I have fills the blanks but the numbers I get are wrong and I do not understand why. Plus if there is no number in column B (first day of the month) the macro stops running.
 Here is a part of the code I am using so far (probably full of errors and not optimized):

```
Sub FillLinear()

Dim rng As Range
Dim stepValue As Integer

Set rng = Range("B2", Range("B2").End(xlToRight))
On Error Resume Next


Do
   'Compute the difference between the first & last cell in the range,
   ' divided by the number of blank cells + 1.
   stepValue = (rng(rng.Cells.Count).Value - rng(1).Value) / _
            (rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Count + 1)
On Error Resume Next
   'now we can use our computed "stepValue" instead of hard-coding it as a     constant:
   '## Use the resize method to avoid overwriting the last cell in this range
    rng.Resize(, rng.Cells.Count - 1).DataSeries Rowcol:=xlRows, _
               Type:=xlLinear, _
               Date:=xlDay, _
               Step:=stepValue, _
               Trend:=False


   'Increment the range to the next row
   Set rng = Range(rng(1).Offset(1), rng(1).Offset(1).End(xlToRight))

'Escape the loop only when we reach an empty/blank cell in the first column:
Loop Until Trim(rng(1).Value) = vbNullString

On Error Resume Next

Set rng = Range("C2", Range("C2").End(xlToRight))

Do
   'Compute the difference between the first & last cell in the range,
   ' divided by the number of blank cells + 1.
   stepValue = (rng(rng.Cells.Count).Value - rng(1).Value) / _
            (rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Count + 1)
On Error Resume Next
   'now we can use our computed "stepValue" instead of hard-coding it as a     constant:
   '## Use the resize method to avoid overwriting the last cell in this range
    rng.Resize(, rng.Cells.Count - 1).DataSeries Rowcol:=xlRows, _
               Type:=xlLinear, _
               Date:=xlDay, _
               Step:=stepValue, _
               Trend:=False


   'Increment the range to the next row
   Set rng = Range(rng(1).Offset(1), rng(1).Offset(1).End(xlToRight))

'Escape the loop only when we reach an empty/blank cell in the first column:
Loop Until Trim(rng(1).Value) = vbNullString

On Error Resume Next

Set rng = Range("D2", Range("D2").End(xlToRight))

Do
   'Compute the difference between the first & last cell in the range,
   ' divided by the number of blank cells + 1.
   stepValue = (rng(rng.Cells.Count).Value - rng(1).Value) / _
            (rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Count + 1)
On Error Resume Next
   'now we can use our computed "stepValue" instead of hard-coding it as a    constant:
   '## Use the resize method to avoid overwriting the last cell in this range
     rng.Resize(, rng.Cells.Count - 1).DataSeries Rowcol:=xlRows, _
               Type:=xlLinear, _
               Date:=xlDay, _
               Step:=stepValue, _
               Trend:=False


   'Increment the range to the next row
    Set rng = Range(rng(1).Offset(1), rng(1).Offset(1).End(xlToRight))

 'Escape the loop only when we reach an empty/blank cell in the first column:
Loop Until Trim(rng(1).Value) = vbNullString

On Error Resume Next

 Set rng = Range("E2", Range("E2").End(xlToRight))

Do
   'Compute the difference between the first & last cell in the range,
   ' divided by the number of blank cells + 1.
   stepValue = (rng(rng.Cells.Count).Value - rng(1).Value) / _
            (rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Count + 1)
On Error Resume Next
   'now we can use our computed "stepValue" instead of hard-coding it as a    constant:
   '## Use the resize method to avoid overwriting the last cell in this range
     rng.Resize(, rng.Cells.Count - 1).DataSeries Rowcol:=xlRows, _
               Type:=xlLinear, _
               Date:=xlDay, _
               Step:=stepValue, _
               Trend:=False


   'Increment the range to the next row
   Set rng = Range(rng(1).Offset(1), rng(1).Offset(1).End(xlToRight))

'Escape the loop only when we reach an empty/blank cell in the first column:
Loop Until Trim(rng(1).Value) = vbNullString


End Sub
```

So far I did not find any other solution than copy paste the same code forst every column.

Comment: What do you mean that you want to fill it in a linear way? For instance, in the example you gave what do you want day 3 of January to be the average of the two neighbouring values, i.e. `(4.23% + 3.21%) / 2 = 3.72%`? Or some function of the first and last value of the row? I only skimmed the code as it seems to do a bit more than just filling in the blanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to suggest a slightly different approach. But that is of course merely personal preference. In this solution I am going through all the cells left to right and top to bottom starting with cell B2 always sampling for empty cells and keeping track of the last cell with a value.

Once an empty range - between two filled cells - has been identified a second sub is called to fille this range. In short, this is the solution I am proposing:

```
Option Compare Text
Option Explicit
Option Base 0

Public Sub FillLinear()
Dim strLastRange, strToRange As String
Dim intCountBlanks As Integer
Dim lngRow, lngColumn As Long

For lngRow = 2 To 2000000000
    If IsEmpty(Cells(lngRow, 1).Value2) Then Exit For
    For lngColumn = 2 To 100
        If IsEmpty(Cells(1, lngColumn).Value2) Then Exit For
        If Cells(lngRow, lngColumn).Value2 = vbNullString Then
            If Not strLastRange = vbNullString Then
                intCountBlanks = intCountBlanks + 1
            End If
        Else
            If strLastRange = vbNullString Then
                strLastRange = Cells(lngRow, lngColumn).Address
            Else
                If intCountBlanks = 0 Then
                    strLastRange = Cells(lngRow, lngColumn).Address
                Else
                    strToRange = Cells(lngRow, lngColumn).Address
                    Call FillThemUp(strLastRange, strToRange, intCountBlanks)
                    strLastRange = strToRange
                End If
            End If
            intCountBlanks = 0
        End If
    Next lngColumn
Next lngRow

End Sub

Public Sub FillThemUp(ByVal strLastRange As String, ByVal strToRange As String, ByVal intCountBlanks As Integer)
Dim lngRow, lngColumn As Long
Dim strLastCell As String
Dim lngCountDown As Long
Dim bolStart As Boolean

lngCountDown = intCountBlanks
intCountBlanks = intCountBlanks + 1
For lngRow = 2 To 2000000000
    If IsEmpty(Cells(lngRow, 1).Value2) Then Exit For
    For lngColumn = 2 To 100
        If IsEmpty(Cells(1, lngColumn).Value2) Then Exit For
        If lngRow = Range(strLastRange).Row And lngColumn = Range(strLastRange).Column Then bolStart = True
        If bolStart = True Then
            If IsEmpty(Cells(lngRow, lngColumn).Value2) Then
                Cells(lngRow, lngColumn).Formula = "=" & strLastCell & "-((" & strLastRange & "-" & strToRange & ")/" & intCountBlanks & ")"
                Cells(lngRow, lngColumn).Interior.ColorIndex = 36
                lngCountDown = lngCountDown - 1
            End If
            strLastCell = Cells(lngRow, lngColumn).Address
        End If
        If lngCountDown = 0 Then Exit Sub
    Next lngColumn
Next lngRow

End Sub
```